# If statement c++ with text

Tags: c++

My code:

```
{

    int reply;

    cout<<"Am I doing something wrong: ";
    cin>> reply;



    if-part( reply == "yes") {
    cout<<"Good";
    }


    }
```

Hi guys, I am newbie, I googled and youtubed the stuff, but i just can not find an answer.

Why is this code not running well if you text in if condition, but if you put number, everything is fine?

Thank you.

Comment: what is `if-part` ??

Comment: `reply` is an `int`, and `cin` won't accept a string as valid input for `reply`.

Comment: `int`s aren't `string`s.

Comment: May I ask how do i fix it then? thank you.

Comment: ok i put string instead of int. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you need to be able to accept a string or a number, then you must read a string then check to see if that string is a number.

Comment: I recommend reading a basic tutorial on C++ syntax before trying to write any code. `if-part`? and then in your own answer you wrote what it should be an `else if`without actually writing the `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you are comparing an integer with a pointer (address)

```
if-part( reply == "yes") {
```

`Reply` is a in value.

"yes" is a c-string, so it is roughly equivalent to

```
const char *yes = "yes"
```

where `yes` would be a pointer to the first byte in the string in y_e_s -- for example, 0x75243

so you are comparing an integer value  to a pointer value such as  0x75243  and they are unlikely to ever be equal.

In java script this would work (better) since it converts types for you -- C++ does not, at least not like this.

Answer (score 0):

`reply` is of type `int` and you are comparing it as a `string`.That's not possible.

Comment: You must have `reply`  of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
if (reply == 1)
     cout << "Good\n";
```